# XSLT - add one level for multivalued

Tags: xslt

Could you help me with create a code which would be able to convert data as below.
I need to add one level to data contained in entry. Data come from multivalued attribute but are writing as single row. I don't know how to do this and asking for your help.

I have this code but it doesn't work as I expect. If don't know XLST so this is a reason why I ask.

```
<entry>
 <c>PL</c>
 <cn>dackjo</cn>
 <department>FO</department>
 <givenName>Joe</givenName>
 <plant>Berlin</plant>
 <plant>Praga</plant>
 <sec>admin</sec>
 <sec>worker</sec>
 <ou>PL</ou>
 <sn>Dack</sn>
 <title>worker</title>
 <preferredLanguage>EN</preferredLanguage>
 <uid>u12c55cb--4efe</uid>
 <timezone>CET</timezone>
</entry>
```

I have to convert values as above to format below. We need to add one
level and group multivalues behind it.
expected output:

```
 <entry>
  <c>PL</c>
  <cn>dackjo</cn>
  <department>FO</department>
  <givenName>Joe</givenName>
  <Plants>
     <plant>Berlin</plant>
     <plant>Praga</plant>
  </Plants>
  <SecRoles>
     <sec>admin</sec>
     <sec>admin</sec>
  </SecRoles>  
  <ou>PL</ou>
  <sn>Dack</sn>
  <title>worker</title>
  <preferredLanguage>EN</preferredLanguage>
  <uid>u12c55cb--4efe</uid>
  <timezone>CET</timezone>
 </entry>
```

Comment: It's kind of required that you actually are doing some of the work on your own, instead of stopping by here and asking around if someone can write code for you. Grouping in XSLT is an extremely common operation, and one of the, if not *the* most frequently asked question type... but this is not even a grouping problem, this is much simpler. How far have you gotten with your own attempt?

Comment: The issue is that I hava a problem and im not a developer. Application has a translation code but unfortunately I never work with xslt code.

Comment: Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports. Also clarify if the order of elements on the output matters (i.e. can the `Plants` group be the first or the last child of `entry`.

Answer (score 0):

An output similar - but not identical - to yours could be produced using:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/entry">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except plant"/>
        <Plants>
            <xsl:copy-of select="plant"/>
        </Plants>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--
Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rWW

Comment: Thank you for help,
in this solution issue appear when we have another multivalued attribute,
my intention was collect multivalued ( the same) and add one level, doesn't matter how many multivalued field we have got at employee entry
for instance : parent: "securityRoles" ,child: securityRole, admin, worker,

Comment: what if when multivalued attribute, appear, my intention was collect multivalued and add one level, doesn't matter how many multivalued field we have got at employee entry
for instance : parent: "secRoles" ,child: sec, admin, worker,
I corrected input, once again

Comment: If you mean that you want to create a wrapper element  for any group of elements having the same name, then your question is about *grouping*. Read this link and come back (preferably with a new question) if you get stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this topic. Maybe not sophisticated but it works at the moment.

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="UserName"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="isRetired" />
<xsl:copy-of select="Language"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="FirstName" />
<xsl:copy-of select="LastName"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="Email" />
<xsl:copy-of select="EmployeeCode"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="ExEmployee" />
<xsl:copy-of select="MobilePhone"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="JobTitle" />
<xsl:copy-of select="Location"/>
<Plants>
 <xsl:copy-of select="Plant" />
</Plants>
<Security>
 <xsl:copy-of select="Role" />
</Security>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Two questions: 
1. Do you only create a Plants element when there is more than one?
2. Is there a convention/business-rule what the new container element name should be if there are more than one elements in the source?

Comment: Actually, this does NOT work with the given example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTJS. In any case, if that's what you learned from this ...